# Does anyone know where ASP themes are?

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know where I can go to get some ASP themes for Visual Studio? I've Googled it, but it doesn't seem that there are many out there. I was hoping someone here knew something that I don't. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has nothing to do with it. The CSS for a custom theme will have rules that are applied to the HTML elements rendered to the page. The structure of your HTML can vary greatly; every developer/designer have their own preferences about whether to place certain parts of the page on a form or on a master page. There is no standard way of doing this and each project will have its own set of requirements in this regard.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/705sff8d%28VS.80%29.aspx

There really is nothing to learning how to create an ASPNET theme. If it's the CSS part that is causing you difficulty then your best bet is to install the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox and view some CSS galleries. This tool will then allow you to investigate how some really professional sites are put together.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Answer (score 0):

i think you must have to create your own CSS.